# how do i push the content instead of overlay on the panel slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, panel

i managed to make the sliding panel work but instead of overlay i want it to push the whole site to left
this is my fiddle
http: //jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Dw6yK/1/

body {
    position: relative;
    min - height: 3000px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    font - family: 'proximanova-regular',
    sans - serif;
}

Answer (score 0):

To appear from left, make the below changes to your code.

```
#panel-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: i dont want it to appear from left i just want it to push content and not overlay. im sorry for not being clear

Comment: can you put some content on that div and update the fiddle? - @San

Comment: Hi nathan just updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Dw6yK/1/ i want the panel like this when you hover mouse on right top tumblr button  http://yahoo.tumblr.com/